# Semantic zoom controls for WPF?

Tags: wpf, controls, semantic-zoom

WinRT/Metro is getting a new [SemanticZoom](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/winrt-tutorial-mvvm-gridview-semanticzoom.aspx) control, but I'm having a hard time finding anything for WPF.

I don't want to switch to Metro for my particular project, because it doesn't allow me to make windowed apps or multiple instances across multiple monitors.

Are there any third party semantic zoom controls for WPF?

Answer (score 1):

I know your asking for controls, but you could also use the [ZoomableCanvas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2010/07/29/zoomablecanvas.aspx) Code as a basis for your own implementation of semantic zoom. I've planned to implement this for a timeline project myself and maybe add it on CodeProject.

Comment: any news on this ?   :p

Comment: @user2475096 I didn't look further into semantic zooms back then, I just used thed the ZoomableCanvas.